# What is the difference between using callback functions and calling a static function directly in java?

Tags: java, callback

I know this question has been asked before. But I want to understand the difference with the perspective of my code.

So here is the scenario.

I have a class Main.java. This class calls a different class Secondary.java . On a particular method in the Secondary class, I want some values in the Main class to be updated. There are two ways to do this.

1) One way for doing this is through Callback functions in java.
2) Second is if I define a static function in Main class, then call the static function from Secondary Class.

Here are my two approaches.

Approach 1

**Interface CallBack.java**

```
   public Interface Callback{
       public void  updateValues();
    }
```

**Main.java**

```
 public class Main implements Callback {

        static int a=1;
        public static void main(String args[]) {

        Callback callback = new Main();
        Secondary obj = new Secondary(callback);
        obj.onClick();
    }

    public void updateValues(){
       a = 4;
    }

}
```

**Secondary.java**

```
 public class Secondary{

    private Callback callback;

    Secondary (Callback callback) {
    this.callback=callback;
     }    

    //On this method click, I want to update values in the Main class 
    public void onClick(){
        callback.updateValues();
    }
  }
```

**Approach 2**

```
     public class Main {

            static int a=1;
            public static void main(String args[]) {

            Second obj = new Second();
            obj.onClick();
        }
        public static void updateValues(){
           a = 4;
        }
}
public class Secondary{

    Secondary () {
    //On this method click, I want to update values in the Main class
    public void onClick(){
        Main.updateValues();
    }
```

}

So I just want to know that which approach is better? When are callback functions really useful?

Note: This is just an example to understand  the difference between the two concepts.

Comment: This is called **tight coupling**. `Main` has to know about `Secondary` and `Secondary` has to know about `Main`. This means that neither can change without the other changing. This is a **big** no-no. You also have zero re-usability.

Comment: That doesnot answer my question.

Comment: It certainly does. "Callback functions are useful because they prevent tight coupling and encourage the writing of reusable code, see above".

Answer (score 3):

Which approach is better?  The answer always depends on context, there are cases to break every rule.  That said, keeping coupling low and code simple and unit tested are the usual priorities.

```
static method
  pros:          simple, and direct
  disadvantages: the static method cannot be substituted with 
                 other implementations.    

callback approach
  pros: easy to substitute callbacks, good for mocking in tests
  cons: a little more overhead for the callback (although JVMs 
       can often optimise them out) and a little more conceptual 
       cost to developers; which will be low if they are not abused.
```

Judging by your choice of example, I suspect that you are working on a GUI.  With large applications, the static method approach does not tend to scale without becoming brittle to change.  So while your application is small, you will find that the static method approach is simple and tempting.  However as your application grows, and you add more people to the project who all need to make changes to the growing code base at the same time we need ways to isolate parts of the application and to unit test those parts.  This is where the callback approach shines.

The danger with the callback approach is that it becomes over used.  Avoid nesting callbacks as much as possible (there are patterns from the functional world that make this a great technique, but perhaps that is for another post) and the callback must not know about the caller.  A cyclic dependency tends to complicate code at a non-linear rate.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer Approach 2 from what you described. That leaves me with principle called open for extension and closed for modification.

So tomorrow if i have a new Callback i could inject it directly in it and use updateValue method.

If i have ever to follow the approach one then this means:

- I am breaking OOP principle by using static. You would not be able to override static method.
- If tomorrow your updateValue needs change you are going to change Main which breaks closed for modification principle
- This would close the doors of further reusability as well.